# How to assign a hotkey to 'set origin' context menu?

Tags: interface, workflow, shortcut

How can I assign a shortcut to popup the following menu when pressed?

[image]

I have looked around and I found that I can right click and "Assign shortcut" on other menus, like this example on pivot point, but I can't do it on that submenu.

[image]

Also, I tried the method of looking on the *Python Console* to find out the value of that menu, but there's no value on that one (just on the sub choices).

Comment: It's already part of *Object context menu* (*Select the object, Right-click > Set Origin*). Is that fast enough for your purpose?

Comment: I noticed that, but I was looking for a quicker way, like the "m" for move to collection that shows the menu without having to go through submenus.

Comment: Yeah, get it. By looking through the ui code, you'll see that `object.origin_set` operator is called via `Layout.operator_menu_enum()`, not quite sure there is any way adding that to the keymap. In case there is no option you'll have to write a custom operator (addon) or wait until following "bug" is fixed: https://developer.blender.org/T65704

Comment: Ah!, Thanks!. I see, I though It was me that I couldn't find it.
Although as you say, I wouldn't see that as a "bug" more like a "feature request".

Comment: If you set the keymap to Blender 27X in the Preferences, you can find it under the name: Set Origin. Originally: ctrl+shift+alt+c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a *new key map item* under *3D View > Object Non-modal* and set the *identifier* to `object.origin_set` ([`bl_idname`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Operator.html#bpy.types.Operator.bl_idname) for [`Object.origin_set()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.object.html#bpy.ops.object.origin_set) operator).  In order to match the definition of the hotkey in 2.7x, set the event to <kbd>C</kbd> and enable <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> for the modifier keys:

[image]

**Note:** Assigning shortcuts to enum menus like this *(operator in this case)*, is a known limitation and will hopefully supported in the near future: https://developer.blender.org/T65704

Comment: Where did your get that "object.origin_set" value?. I'm asking so I can look for myself next time. thank you for the help!.

Comment: From the source file as stated in [my second comment](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/147996/how-to-assign-a-key-to-toggle-set-origin-contex-menu#comment252614_147996). *Right-click > Edit Source*. Just make sure *Developer Extras* enabled under *Preferences > Interface* to have that option within the context menu @Fabman

Comment: I didn't have the developer extras enabled, now I see it.