# How to assign shortcut to Snap menu

Tags: shortcut

I wanted to assign similar hot keys on Snap menu and setting Origin menu  like shift + f1 and ctrl + f1 since you can't add Origin menu to Quick Favorite

After seeing [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/147996/how-to-assign-a-hotkey-to-set-origin-context-menu), I managed to make it for setting Origin, but I couldn't for Snap
[image]

I only found those on google
bpy.ops.view3d.snap_cursor_to_active()
bpy.ops.view3d.snap_cursor_to_center()
bpy.ops.view3d.snap_cursor_to_grid()
bpy.ops.view3d.snap_selected_to_active()
bpy.ops.view3d.snap_cursor_to_selected()
bpy.ops.view3d.snap_selected_to_cursor

which are options under Snap menu.
I hope there's a way to round them up as one shortcut button (not as a quick favorite menu)

Comment: Doesn't SHFT+S work for opening the snap menu?

Comment: @Nate_Sycro27 thats a pie menu which disappears if you release shift first

Comment: fill that empty blank with "action.snap", which will bring you that menu.

Comment: @Nate_Sycro27 it doesn't bring that menu. it seems its related to animation snapping which has sub menu for Current frame.

Answer (score 1):

To set the snap menu in Blender, you must open Blender preferences, and go to the input tab.

In the search blank, type "snap keys". One result-*snap keys* should show up. As you showed in the picture, the blank for controlling this action with a shortcut was empty. If no results show up, then make a new shortcut with these settings:

[image]